# Using an RPI-5 w/ Bookworm GPIOZERO errors on setting GPIO pins 4, 17 & 18, but all the others work fine. What am I missing? See code below

Tags: gpiozero

I am trying to use GPIO pin 4 for control of a purchased circuit board and there's seems to be an issue with 3 of the GPIO pins. The simple code below illustrates the issue.  For visual diagnostics I'm driving a GPIO Status LED & Breakout Board (https://store.freenove.com/products/fnk0080).  The order of the GPIO #'s follows the physical layout so the lights will sequentially circle around the header EXCEPT for Pins 4, 17 & 18 ... these 3 pins generate the error: lgpio.error: 'GPIO busy'.  Using "Raspberry Pi Configuration" all of the interfaces have been turned off, so there shouldn't be any conflicting usage.  For test completeness pins 2 thru 27 are included.

What am I missing?

Here's the OS info ...
pi@pi:~ $ uname -a
Linux pi 6.1.0-rpi8-rpi-2712 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.73-1+rpt1 (2024-01-25) aarch64 GNU/Linux

Here's the RPI info ...
pi@pi:~ $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 6.1.0-rpi8-rpi-2712 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-12 (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.40) #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.73-1+rpt1 (2024-01-25)

Try it yourself ...

```
from gpiozero import LEDBoard
from time import sleep
leds = LEDBoard( 2, 3,
                 #4,  # generates lgpio.error: 'GPIO busy' 
                 #17, # generates lgpio.error: 'GPIO busy'
                 27, 22, 10, 9, 11, 5, 6, 13, 19, 26,
                 21, 20, 16, 12, 7, 8, 25, 24, 23,
                 #18, # generates lgpio.error: 'GPIO busy'
                 15, 14 )
while True:
    for led in leds:
        led.on()
        sleep(.5)
        led.off()
```